# A large dataset not partitioned joins another one large dataset, partitioned. Is the result dataset partitioned or not?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

On `Spark`, I have an enterprise dataset listing companies in France. It's large (1 Gb CSV file) and is loaded without partitions.

I have another dataset : etablishments (of these companies), a large file too, who have a location setting them in a department in France. This department has a number that goes from 01 to 98 and this number is used to partition the etablishments.

When I do a `enterprise.join(etablishments, joinKey)` what becomes the result dataset ?
- Is it stored on etablishment partitions (that would be convenient),
- or is it left unpartitioned ?

Would it be the same if I did a `etablishments.join(enterprise, joinKey)` ?

Comment: How about trying firstly?

Comment: I did, but I don't know how to check. My program is an embedded jar running Spark by itself. It is not on a Spark web-UI or any tool able to show me where chunks are.

Comment: Do via spark  ‍♀️ in cluster mode

Comment: the you can run .explain

Comment: The java application is an auto-executable jar in local mode and there is no other Spark environment set. I run a `java -jar app.jar` and it does it works. I have no way to check where the chunks are put. Except if this is shown on console logs.

Comment: OK, got it. But do you have source code?

Comment: If so you can check with a databricks community account reasonably well.

Comment: Well What is large?

Comment: Will check tomorrow but all assumption based.

Comment: Hashing on joinkey snd hence output as well if memory serves correctly with shuffling. See https://github.com/vaquarkhan/Apache-Kafka-poc-and-notes/wiki/Apache-Spark-Join-guidelines-and-Performance-tuning

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assuming dataframes, datasets and not RDDs.
2. Assuming read in from files.
3. Assuming no range partitioning, etc.

> In answer to your question: The resulting dataframe will also be
>   partitioned in some way, that is your answer. How could it not be as
>   in general partitioning allows parallel processing a la Spark
>   paradigm.

Take this example simple example:

```
val ds1 = df0.repartition(765)
val ds2 = df0.repartition(765)
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "765")
val joined = ds1.join(ds2, ds1("time_asc") === ds2("time_asc"), "outer")
```

Hashing for JOIN occurs per default (if not already the case) and 765 filled or empty partitions are created and processed. The resultant output DF has also 765 partitions.

If you aggr, join, etc and do not set the above parameter, the Spark 200 default will apply, or the value as per last set in your Spark Session.

With small broadcast table, the resulting partitions on output will be equal to number of partitions from non-broadcasted - the larger - table.

Hope this helps.